# Are there other convergence tests for series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, soft-question

I was reading [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests) Wikipedia entry on convergence tests for series to see if there were any tests we didn't go over in my calculus lectures. The ones listed in the entry but we didn't cover in class are the Gauss' test and Kummer's test. My question is: Does that entry mention all the existing convergence test for series? Or are there any other(s) not mentioned in that list?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is a book by Knopp on series that discusses different tests.

Comment: @orangeskid You mean the book titled Theory and Application of Infinite series, right?

Comment: Yes, that one. It is very thorough.